# How to change OpenCV version of any ros package?

Tags: ros, opencv, ros-melodic, catkin-ws, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Example ;

```
find_package(RTABMap 0.19.5 REQUIRED)

find_package(OpenCV 4.2.0 REQUIRED)

find_package(PCL 1.7 REQUIRED)
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS}) # To include -march=native if set

catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS include
  LIBRARIES rtabmap_ros
  CATKIN_DEPENDS cv_bridge roscpp rospy sensor_msgs std_msgs std_srvs nav_msgs geometry_msgs visualization_msgs
                 image_transport tf tf_conversions tf2_ros eigen_conversions laser_geometry pcl_conversions 
                 pcl_ros nodelet dynamic_reconfigure message_filters class_loader rosgraph_msgs
                 stereo_msgs move_base_msgs image_geometry ${optional_dependencies}
  DEPENDS RTABMap OpenCV
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
# include_directories(include)
include_directories(
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
  ${RTABMap_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

# libraries
SET(Libraries
   ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}
   ${PCL_LIBRARIES}
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
   ${RTABMap_LIBRARIES}
)
```

It works like this when compiled.

I just changed the find_package () section.

Is it necessary to make changes in other parts? For Example
in catkin_package ().

catkin_package (  DEPENDS RTABMap OpenCV )

to

catkin_package (  DEPENDS RTABMap OpenCV 4.2.0 )

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/346231/how-to-change-opencv-version-of-any-ros-package?/) by [jahim44229](https://answers.ros.org/users/51940/jahim44229/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2020-03-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`find_package(OpenCV 4.2.0 REQUIRED)`  is enough. You dont need to specify the version later on I think. 
Check the following [question](https://answers.ros.org/question/58498/what-is-the-purpose-of-catkin_depends/). It gives a good explanation on how to use CMake macros.

Also dont forget to link the libraries:

```
target_link_libraries(your_executable
${catkin_LIBRARIES}
${OpenCV_LIBRARIES}
)
```

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2020-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0